# NHibernate mapping to two versions of Table

Tags: nhibernate

I have a table that has two versions
e.g.
TableVersion1 with columns: A, B, C, 
TableVersion2 with columns: A, B, C, D

how do I write an entity that will work on both versions of table?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work for you.  This is fluent syntax but you get the idea. This is assuming that both versions of this table exist in the same database.  If they aren't I don't think this can be done.

```
public class TableVersionMap : ClassMap<TableVersion>
{
    public TableVersionMap()
    {
        Table("TableVersion1");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.A);
        Map(x => x.B);
        Map(x => x.C);

       Join("TableVersion2", uc =>
       {
           uc.KeyColumn("Id");
           uc.Map(x => x.D);
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show me some document url I can look into for more detailed explanation on this topic

Comment: First of all are these two tables in the same database or are they in different versions of the database?

Comment: They are in different version of the database

Comment: Then this solution will not work.  You can't do what you're asking.  You need to have two different versions of your binaries that contain the mappings and use the older version when running against the older version of the database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to map the same class to two different tables. In this case you should use different entity names in your mappings. As you haven't specified your mapping preferences I'll use hbm in my example.

```
<class entity-name="ArtistA" name="Artist" table="artist_a">
    <id name="Id" column="artist_a_id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="artist_a_name" not-null="true" />
</class>

<class entity-name="ArtistB" name="Artist" table="artist_b">
    <id name="Id" column="artist_b_id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="artist_b_name" not-null="true" />
</class>
```

Note the presence of the entity-name attribute. When persisting an entity you should specify entity name.

```
session.Save("ArtistA", new Artist { ... });
```